# vb.net WinForms Highlight PDF

Tags: vb.net, winforms, activex

I will like to highlight words on PDF using application written by Visual Basic WinForms in Visual Studio

My approach is to add reference to Adobe Acrobat library, ActiveX library so as to instantiate a jso object that can allow me to annotate on PDF (highlight).

However, I faced the following problems:
#1 : When clicking on the button for the first time, the code returns me a pdf that is highlighted but only at the lower left of the PDF.
#2 : Upon clicking further times, the application will be unresponsive and the error will appear : Cannot create ActiveX component (linked to gApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App"))

I am new to this . I hope I will get advice on this . Thank you.

[tag:Public Class Form1
Dim gApp As Acrobat.CAcroApp

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    gApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Closed(Cancel As Integer)
    If Not gApp Is Nothing Then
        gApp.Exit()
    End If
    gApp = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim pdDoc As Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc
    Dim page As Acrobat.CAcroPDPage
    Dim jso As Object
    Dim path As String
    Dim point(1) As Integer
    Dim popupRect(3) As Integer
    Dim annot As Object
    Dim props As Object
    
    Dim no_of_pages As Integer
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim word As String
    Dim quads As System.Object
    Dim pageRect As Object
    Dim i, j, k As Integer

    

    pdDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")

    Using OpenFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog()
        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()

        path = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        Debug.WriteLine(path)
        If pdDoc.Open(path) Then

            

            jso = pdDoc.GetJSObject
            If Not jso Is Nothing Then

                page = pdDoc.AcquirePage(0)
                pageRect = page.GetSize
                Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("pageRect {0}", pageRect.y))
                no_of_pages = pdDoc.GetNumPages
                For j = 0 To no_of_pages - 1
                    count = jso.getPageNumWords(j)
                    For i = 0 To count - 1
                        word = jso.getPageNthWord(j, i)
                        Debug.WriteLine(word)
                        If LCase(word) = "hello" Then
                            quads = (jso.getPageNthWordQuads(j, i))
                            Debug.WriteLine(quads.Length)
                            
                            
                            popupRect(0) = quads(0)(0)
                            popupRect(1) = quads(0)(5)
                            popupRect(2) = quads(0)(2) - quads(0)(0)
                            popupRect(3) = quads(0)(1) - quads(0)(5)
                            
                            
                        End If
                    Next
                Next

                annot = jso.AddAnnot
                props = annot.getProps

                props.Type = "Highlight"
                annot.setProps(props)

                props = annot.getProps
                props.page = 0
               
                props.popupRect = popupRect
                props.author = "John Doe"
               
                props.strokeColor = jso.Color.Yellow
                props.Contents = "I added this comment from Visual Basic!"
                annot.setProps(props)

            End If

            pdDoc.Close()
            MsgBox("Annotation added to " & path)

        Else
            MsgBox("Failed to open " & path)
        End If
        pdDoc = Nothing
    End Using
    gApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

End Class
]

Comment: Not really my specialty, but are you 100% sure at the end of Button1_Click you want to be doing `gApp = Nothing`?

Comment: Thank you for the help :) I removed it and it is still not working.